# Mysql count 2 rows in one query

Tags: php, mysql

I am counting today's added rows in mySQL using

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total 
FROM track 
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(date,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s') > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY");
```

This works successfully. However, I also want to count today's added rows which includes a number greater than "0" in it's column named "conv".

I have tried

```
mysql_query("SELECT conv,COUNT(*) as total
FROM track 
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(date,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s') > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY");
```

But it doesn't counted. What is the correct way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will count both the rows, and the rows in which conv is greater than zero:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS total,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN conv THEN 1 END) AS total_conv_greater
FROM
  ...
```

If conv>0 CASE WHEN will return a non-Null value, otherwise it will return Null, and COUNT() will count only non-null values.

Comment: So ı shouldn't use "as total", so where these counts will be stored in ?

Answer (score 0):

usage of `CASE` Syntax could be a great help i think

Resource link([source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html))